# Whatsapp Message Layouting - time and message in the same row

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, cocoa

I was wondering how WhatsApp handles the time shown in every message.

For those who don't know:

- If the message is very short, the text and time are in the same row. (tine in the end of row)
- If the message is long, the time is in the bottom right corner - the text wrapped around it.

if you have some idea how to do it please let me know

Here is the requested screenshot (please ignore checkmarks):
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use a single attributed string with different text attributes for the main message, and the timestamp. iOS will then internally do all this for you automatically.

Otherwise you can use exclusion paths which are a part of TextKit.

Comment: It will be not works with text attributes, you can see it on my the last image (time stamp should be in the end)
It will painful use exclusion paths for this case. when exclusion should be in the end of text. As I know there are some issue with find right height of textview when you are using exclusion

Comment: Did you find its solution?

Comment: did you find a solution please

Comment: Did you get any solution for this

Comment: Checkout this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30168465/whatsapp-message-layout-how-to-get-time-view-in-the-same-row