# How to construct whatsapp timestamp layout using layoutkit?

Tags: swift, layout, uikit, linkedin-api

[image]

I try to construct this message bubble layout using layoutKit. I was using the stackLayout to construct this as follow but it's not able to render dynamic position of the timestamp and the message. The timestamp will locate horizontally in the stack but if the message is longer, the timestamp will locate vertically in the stack.

Can anyone tell me how to construct this layout?

```
class LayoutSample1: SizeLayout<View> {
    init(messageLayout: Layout, timeStampLayout: Layout) {

        let stackLayout = StackLayout(
            axis: .vertical,
            distribution: .fillFlexing,
            sublayouts: [messageLayout, timeStampLayout],
            config: { view in
                view.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange
        })

        super.init(
            sublayout: stackLayout,
            config: { view in
                view.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
        })
    }
}


class TimestampLayout: LabelLayout<UILabel> {

    init(text: String) {

        super.init(
            text: Text.unattributed(text),
            font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12),
            numberOfLines: 0,
            alignment: .bottomTrailing,
            config: { label in
                label.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        })
    }
}

class MessageLayout: LabelLayout<UILabel> {
    init(text: String) {
        super.init(
            text: Text.unattributed(text),
            font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14),
            numberOfLines: 0,
            alignment: .topLeading,
            config: { label in
                label.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. While sub-layouts of the `StackLayout` should be non-intersecting rectangles, this should be much easier to use the [`OverlayLayout`](https://github.com/linkedin/LayoutKit/blob/bdc0fdc9407d9e4cefc773401bf51e22779201bc/Sources/Layouts/OverlayLayout.swift) instead.
2. You have to consider the case when the last line of the message is overlapped by the timestamp. To solve that you can layout strings manually like it is done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39830788). Another way is to append some whitespace characters to the message. I found that UIKit doesn't trim the [`Braille pattern blank`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Braille_Patterns) symbol (`U+2800`), so it can be appended at the end.

Here is the example:

```
class LayoutSample1: SizeLayout<View> {

    init(message: String, timeStamp: String, maxWidth: CGFloat = 200) {
        let messageLayout = InsetLayout(
            inset: 4,
            sublayout: LabelLayout(
                text: message + "\u{2003}\u{2003}\u{2800}",
                font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14)) {
                    $0.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
            }
        )

        let timeStampLayout = LabelLayout(
            text: timeStamp,
            font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12),
            alignment: .bottomTrailing) {
                $0.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        }

        let rootlayout = OverlayLayout(
            primary: messageLayout,
            overlay: [timeStampLayout]) {
                $0.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
        }

        super.init(maxWidth: maxWidth, sublayout: rootlayout)
    }
}
```