# How to set constraint layout minimum width to the width of another view from xml

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

In message row for group messaging set, the minimum (text and time) layout width is the width of the username view. See below images *(see the time alignment)*

```
//Pseudo code
textLayout = text + time 
usernameLayout = senderName

if(usernameLayout == gone){
    textLayout width == wrap_content
}else{
  textLayout minimum width == usernameLayout width  
}
```

Output coming like this

[image: With wrap_content]

Result i want below

[image: With width==0dp]

Layout code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/message_row_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="start|bottom"
android:baselineAligned="false"
android:paddingStart="@dimen/padding_8dp"
android:paddingEnd="40dp">


<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/message_box"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/chat_incoming_bg">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvUserName"
        style="@style/TextStyle.Chat.Item.Name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:paddingEnd="@dimen/padding_8dp"
        android:text="Jarvis Pixel9 New testName "
        android:textColor="@color/red800"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/chat_text_layout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:gravity="start"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvUserName">


        <com.vanniktech.emoji.EmojiTextView
            android:id="@+id/message_body"
            style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/padding_8dp"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/padding_4dp"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/padding_8dp"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/padding_8dp"
            android:text="Hijkhkfjhds"
            android:textColorLink="@color/link_color"
            android:textSize="?attr/TextSizeBody"
            app:emojiSize="28sp"
            tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll_msg_info"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
            android:gravity="end|bottom"
            android:minWidth="60dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingEnd="@dimen/padding_8dp"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/padding_4dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/message_body"
            tools:ignore="RtlSymmetry">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/message_time"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="12:50 PM"
                android:textColor="@color/black54"
                android:textSize="?attr/TextSizeInfo" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img_failed_status"
                android:layout_width="16dp"
                android:layout_height="16dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_cancel_24dp"
                android:visibility="gone" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

If I set `chat_text_layout` width 0dp and `tvUserName` with some text their it's working, but if `tvUserName = gone` then it's not working.

Comment: I hope my answer has resolved your query and if you need further help you can ask.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing lots of trial and error this solution is working

Thanks to [Sinan Ergin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30168465/whatsapp-message-layout-how-to-get-time-view-in-the-same-row/39830788#39830788)  stackoverflow answer.

[image]

**XML layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/message_row_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="start|bottom"
android:baselineAligned="false"
android:paddingStart="@dimen/padding_8dp"
android:paddingEnd="40dp">

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/message_box"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/chat_incoming_bg"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
    <!--User Name -->
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/user_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvContactName"
            style="@style/TextStyle.Chat.Item.Name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
            android:paddingEnd="@dimen/padding_8dp"
            android:textColor="@color/red800"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/tvServerName"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvServerName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxEms="7"
            android:maxLength="20"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/tvContactName"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/tvContactName"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
    <!--Message Layout-->
    <com.shain.views.ChatTextLayout
        android:id="@+id/qt_chat_text_layout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/user_layout"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.50"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_min="wrap"
        app:viewPartMain="@+id/message_body"
        app:viewPartSlave="@+id/ll_msg_info">


        <com.vanniktech.emoji.EmojiTextView
            android:id="@+id/message_body"
            style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/padding_8dp"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/padding_4dp"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/padding_4dp"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/padding_8dp"
            android:textColorLink="@color/link_color"
            android:textSize="?attr/TextSizeBody"
            app:emojiSize="28sp"
            tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll_msg_info"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
            android:gravity="end|bottom"
            android:minWidth="60dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingEnd="@dimen/padding_8dp"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/padding_4dp"
            tools:ignore="RtlSymmetry">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/message_time"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:textColor="@color/black54"
                android:textSize="?attr/TextSizeInfo" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img_failed_status"
                android:layout_width="16dp"
                android:layout_height="16dp"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_cancel_24dp"
                android:visibility="gone" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </com.shain.views.ChatTextLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Java custom view code**

```
public class ChatTextLayout extends ConstraintLayout {

private int widthSize;
private int heightSize;

private TextView viewPartMain;
private View viewPartSlave;
private TypedArray a;

private LayoutParams viewPartMainLayoutParams;
private int viewPartMainWidth;
private int viewPartMainHeight;

private LayoutParams viewPartSlaveLayoutParams;
private int viewPartSlaveWidth;
private int viewPartSlaveHeight;

private boolean withGroupHeader = false;

public ChatTextLayout(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public ChatTextLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.MessageTextStyle, 0, 0);
}

public void setWithGroupHeader(boolean withGroupHeader) {
    this.withGroupHeader = withGroupHeader;
}

@Override
protected void onAttachedToWindow() {
    super.onAttachedToWindow();

    try {
        viewPartMain = this.findViewById(a.getResourceId(R.styleable.MessageTextStyle_viewPartMain, -1));
        viewPartSlave = this.findViewById(a.getResourceId(R.styleable.MessageTextStyle_viewPartSlave, -1));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

    widthSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    heightSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);

    if (viewPartMain == null || viewPartSlave == null || widthSize <= 0) {
        return;
    }

    int availableWidth = widthSize - getPaddingLeft() - getPaddingRight();
    int availableHeight = heightSize - getPaddingTop() - getPaddingBottom();

    viewPartMainLayoutParams = (LayoutParams) viewPartMain.getLayoutParams();
    viewPartMainWidth = viewPartMain.getMeasuredWidth() + viewPartMainLayoutParams.leftMargin + viewPartMainLayoutParams.rightMargin;
    viewPartMainHeight = viewPartMain.getMeasuredHeight() + viewPartMainLayoutParams.topMargin + viewPartMainLayoutParams.bottomMargin;

    viewPartSlaveLayoutParams = (LayoutParams) viewPartSlave.getLayoutParams();
    viewPartSlaveWidth = viewPartSlave.getMeasuredWidth() + viewPartSlaveLayoutParams.leftMargin + viewPartSlaveLayoutParams.rightMargin;
    viewPartSlaveHeight = viewPartSlave.getMeasuredHeight() + viewPartSlaveLayoutParams.topMargin + viewPartSlaveLayoutParams.bottomMargin;

    int viewPartMainLineCount = viewPartMain.getLineCount();
    float viewPartMainLastLineWidth = viewPartMainLineCount > 0 ? viewPartMain.getLayout().getLineWidth(viewPartMainLineCount - 1) : 0;

    widthSize = getPaddingLeft() + getPaddingRight();
    heightSize = getPaddingTop() + getPaddingBottom();

    if (viewPartMainLineCount > 1 && !(viewPartMainLastLineWidth + viewPartSlaveWidth > viewPartMain.getMeasuredWidth())) {
        widthSize += viewPartMainWidth;
        heightSize += viewPartMainHeight;
    } else if (viewPartMainLineCount > 1 && (viewPartMainLastLineWidth + viewPartSlaveWidth > availableWidth)) {
        widthSize += viewPartMainWidth;
        heightSize += viewPartMainHeight + viewPartSlaveHeight;
    } else if (viewPartMainLineCount == 1 && (viewPartMainWidth + viewPartSlaveWidth > availableWidth)) {
        widthSize += viewPartMain.getMeasuredWidth();
        heightSize += viewPartMainHeight + viewPartSlaveHeight;
    } else {
        heightSize += viewPartMainHeight;
        widthSize += viewPartMainWidth + viewPartSlaveWidth;
    }

    this.setMeasuredDimension(widthSize, heightSize);
    super.onMeasure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(widthSize, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY), MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(heightSize, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY));

}

@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
    super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);

    if (viewPartMain == null || viewPartSlave == null) {
        return;
    }
    if (withGroupHeader) {
        viewPartMain.layout(
                getPaddingLeft(),
                getPaddingTop() - Utils.dp(4f),
                viewPartMain.getWidth() + getPaddingLeft(),
                viewPartMain.getHeight() + getPaddingTop());

        viewPartSlave.layout(
                right - left - viewPartSlaveWidth - getPaddingRight(),
                bottom - top - getPaddingBottom() - viewPartSlaveHeight,
                right - left - getPaddingRight(),
                bottom - top - getPaddingBottom());
    } else {
        viewPartMain.layout(
                getPaddingLeft(),
                getPaddingTop(),
                viewPartMain.getWidth() + getPaddingLeft(),
                viewPartMain.getHeight() + getPaddingTop());

        viewPartSlave.layout(
                right - left - viewPartSlaveWidth - getPaddingRight(),
                bottom - top - getPaddingBottom() - viewPartSlaveHeight,
                right - left - getPaddingRight(),
                bottom - top - getPaddingBottom());
    }
  }
}
```

**attrs.xml**

```
 <declare-styleable name="MessageTextStyle">
    <attr name="viewPartMain" format="reference"></attr>
    <attr name="viewPartSlave" format="reference"></attr>
</declare-styleable>
```

Comment: can you share github link for this?

Comment: It's not on Github, but if you have any query I will help you.

Comment: can you upload this on github?

Answer (score 0):

Remove below lines from your `ll_msg_info` as view can work with two constraints only. as you have set `right/end` and `bottom` constraints your layout will work using that.

```
app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/message_body"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, the below code will fulfill your use cases.

**XML Code (for layout):**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/chat">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxWidth="300dp"
        android:text="This Is A Very Long Name As You See"
        android:paddingStart="20dp"
        android:paddingEnd="4dp"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvComment"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxWidth="300dp"
        android:text="This is some comment."
        android:paddingStart="20dp"
        android:paddingEnd="4dp"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvName" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvTime"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="12:50"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:paddingEnd="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="3dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvComment"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**XML Code (for drawable named 'chat'):**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="-45"
            android:pivotX="0%"
            android:pivotY="0%"
            android:toDegrees="0" >
            <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
                <solid android:color="@android:color/holo_green_light" />
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>

    <item android:left="16dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="@android:color/holo_green_light" />
            <corners android:radius="6dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

**Screenshot (of the above code):**

*For screen size - 5.0 inch (1080 x 1920 pixels) [Device: Pixel]*

[image]

You may also run this for different screen sizes, works absolutely fine for me.

I hope, this helps you.

Comment: Hi, I checked it still not very perfect. It has more whitespace and bubble looks big. I am working on something like Whatsapp, where time layout gets adjust based on text size.

Comment: above issue i has resolved with new app:layout_constraintWidth_min="wrap" in constaint layout 1.1.3

Comment: but in bigger text time and text layout overlapping

Comment: In the above mentioned code the time textView is getting adjusted according to the length of both the texts i.e. the name text and the comment text, if you have noticed carefully.

Comment: As well as bubble size can be managed as I have managed it now. :)

Comment: Nitin, Thanks for your effort. I posted my solution with reducing bubble size. please look into.

Comment: I believe, I had edited my answer and then posted it again with reduced bubble size.  :)

Comment: it's not only bubble size, the time layout dynamically adjusts based on text size. that the reason the Whatsapp app chat bubble looks good.

Comment: Yes, you're absolutely right about this, thanks for exploring and sharing about the same.  :)